# How to segment text in PDF files to get out some headings

Tags: pdf, text, nlp, extract, information-extraction

Lets say that i have a couple hundred of PDF file from which i have to extract each heading and the relevant text, for further processing for each heading how do I do that keeping the format of the file.
I have tried PyPDF2 and the pdfminer libraries. These libraries are good in extracting text but I need to get headings and text out separately.
One way could be converting the file to XML maybe that will get out the headings?

As mentioned I have tried PyPDF2 and pdfminer these  are good and extract out all the text in my case but still I cannot get out heading etc for building some context.

Comment: PDF doesn't generally* contain information about headings, footers, etc, it's all just text. So you need to identify such metadata yourself. *Some files may contain tagged or structure information, which may contain such metadata, but most do not.

Comment: You might want to try Adobe Extract API. It reads a PDF and produces JSON that you can use to look for elements that it identifies as headings. You can try it here. https://acrobatservices.adobe.com/dc-visualizer-app/index.html

Comment: The [LEADTOOLS PDF Library](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/pdf) has the [ParsePages](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/dh/pdf/pdfdocument-parsepages.html) method that can parse text objects from PDFs. In addition to the text, the parsed [PDFObject](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/dh/pdf/pdfobject.html) contains additional information such as the font information and color which will assist in determining whether it is part of a heading. (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor)